# Поиск ссылок на python

Tags: python, python-3.x, регулярные-выражения, url

**Поиск всех ссылок заканчивающихся на заданное словосочетание.**
Пример `check?uri=` : `https://validator.w3.org/check?uri=`

Вывести на экран все ссылки или ссылки региона заканчивающееся на `check?uri=`, использую регулярные выражения. Но не знаю как реализовать. Я задавал почти такой же вопрос, но мне не дали конкретного ответа.

Comment: Вам стоит показывать наработки и конкретизировать вопрос. Например, где делаете поиск: в файле с списком url или в html документе. Т.к. от этого зависит выбор инструмента обработки. Для файлика достаточно будет по строчно считать и отфильтровать. Для вебстраницы вытащить парсером html/xml или регулярками (парсер предпочтительнее регулярок). И добавляйте пример данных из которых вы хотите получить нужные куски

Comment: Вам уже отвечали в [удалённом вами вопросе](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/646911/python3-%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba-%d1%81%d1%81%d1%8b%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%ba-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%bd%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%89%d0%b8%d1%85%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%bd%d0%b0-proxy-phpurl-check)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from re import findall
TEXT = '''http://ya.ru/check?uri= qwe http://google.ru/check?uri= ? http://mail.ru'''
urls = 'http[s]?://(?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*\(\),]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+'
result = [url for url in findall(urls, TEXT) if url.rstrip().endswith('check?uri=')]
print(result)  # ['http://ya.ru/check?uri=', 'http://google.ru/check?uri=']
```

Comment: "url for url in findall(urls, TEXT) " я не пойму зачем url , или туда надо что-то вставить?

Comment: тогда начните с основ

Comment: Почему у меня ничего не выводится на экран? я добавил print(url) и ничего не происходит. from re import findall
TEXT = ''' ... '''
urls = 'http[s]?://(?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*\(\),]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+'
for url in findall(urls, TEXT):

 if url.strip().endswith('check?uri='):
  print(url)

Comment: [генераторы списков](https://habrahabr.ru/post/30232/)

Comment: Извините, я очень глуп, я пытался что-то сделать,но у меня всеровно ничего не получается. from re import findall
TEXT = ''' ... '''
urls = 'http[s]?://(?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*\(\),]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+'
for url in findall(urls, TEXT):
 if url.strip().endswith('check?uri='):
  for i in range(b):
   print(i) Пожалуйста, исправьте мой корявый код. Я не могу решить данную проблему уже неделю.

Comment: @Даня Гололобов дополнил код

Answer (score 0):

Думаю что проще использовать стандартную строковую функцию `endswith`:

```
>>> 'https://validator.w3.org/check?uri='.endswith('check?uri=')
>>> True
```